# Heights of 16-month old Oak Seedlings

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The heights of 16-month-old oak seedlings are normally distributed with a mean of 31.5 cm and a standard deviation of 10 cm. What is the range of heights between which 75% of the seedlings will grow?

**My solution:** If 75% of the seedlings grow under this range of heights, then the probability must be 0.75 which is the area under my normal distribution curve. Using the invNorm function on my calculator, I find the z-score to be 0.674. I then know that this is 0.674 standard deviations away from the mean, so I multiply 0.674 by 10, and add them and subtract from my mean to find my range.

My answer is wrong and the correct answer is 20 cm to 43 cm. How am I wrong? What am I supposed to do?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you use the invNorm function? Think of the the normal distribution curve. What part do you want to include? What part do you want to ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the fact that your calculator's invNorm function finds the $z$-value for which $75$ percent of the normal distribution lies between $-\infty$ and $+z$, not between $-z$ and $+z$.  In particular, $50$ percent lies between $-\infty$ and $0$ (obviously, by symmetry) and then another $25$ percent lies between $0$ and $+0.674$.  By symmetry, again, that means that only $50$ percent lies between $-0.674$ and $+0.674$.  If you sketch this out on a notional graph, that might help you to see this difference better.

If your calculator does not have another similar function, we must reason as follows: We want the value of $z$ such that $75$ percent of the normal distribution lies between $-z$ and $+z$.  That means that $37.5$ percent lies between $0$ and $+z$, and therefore that $87.5$ percent lies between $-\infty$ and $+z$.  Apply invNorm to $0.875$ and see if that doesn't give you the right answer.